# Font not display correctly in Firefox on Windows XP

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, windows-xp

On my site i need to use font Interstate Hairline. So I put it on my Fonts folder and put then in my code, css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'interstateHairline';
    url('../fonts/interstate-hairline.ttf') format('truetype'), font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.documents_box ul h4 {
    font-family: "interstateHairline" !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: lowercase
}
```

It's display correct on Windows 7, 8 all browsers. Ubuntu Chrome - correct, Firefox - it's bigger then must be. But main problem it's display not correctly on Windows XP in Firefox/Chrome. All browsers are latest version. Maybe someone have the same situation? 
Sorry for grammar mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by `..not correctly displayed..` ?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot, what do you mean by "not correctly"? ...it's showing up, but how is it showing up?

Comment: I can't add images, but it's displaying like some robot type, but firebug show it like Interstate Hairline ;)

Comment: Just curious, what service pack do you have on the XP system?

Comment: Jordan, i have Service Pack 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Well rendered webfont solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760834/well-rendered-webfont-solution)